# extjs filter combo box based on another combo box value

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am now have editable grid with paging and have two columns, type and value , and they are edited by combo box. I want to have when the column 'type' contains value, the value combo box can filter by the type first. I have implemented a 'beforeload' event to check the if the column type contains value or not and passed as params to the server for retrieve value, however, I found that the combo box is load data to store once only and even the type value is changed, it will not load again.
How can make it load every time based on type value? Can I pass two params to the query ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quite simply with the [`Ext.data.Store.filter()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter) method, like so:

```
//Inside your combobox
listeners: {
    select: function(me) {
        store.clearFilter(true);
        store.filter("storeVariable", me.getRawValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: @newstartgirls In that version you may need to add a `true` to the filter method: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/1.1.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter